# Global name waitForImage/findImage not defined error in Squish 6.2

Tags: python-2.7, squish

I want to use image-based verification in one of my tests, I have read the [froglogic How-To page](https://doc.froglogic.com/squish/latest/ug-imagebasedtesting.html) and tried to use the functions explained there (waitForImage, findImage) but when I execute my test I get the next error:

```
NameError: global name 'waitForImage' is not defined
```

I tried to follow the [tutorial in Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rbhE2q2QLG0) from froglogic to insert the image verification manually but my Squish GUI is different from the version used in the video.

In the page it explains you need to install the tesseract for squish package in order to find text, but it does not specify if you need it for image recognition as well. I am contacting the froglogic team and my IT team but it might take a few days to get a response.

I am using Squish for Java 6.2

I am wondering if that is the reason of my problem or I am skipping any other configuration step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image search feature was [added in Squish 6.3](https://doc.froglogic.com/squish/6.5/rel-630.html). You will need to upgrade to at least Squish 6.3 to use waitForImage and findImage.